# zero an array inside a struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct, memset

I have a struct defined in my program.

```
struct A{
    int arr[10];
}
```

Lets say I have a pointer to it.
`A * a = new A;`

I can zero it in two ways:

```
memset(&a->arr,0,sizeof(A));
memset(a->arr,0,sizeof(A));
```

both work and look the same!

which one is more correct?

Comment: i know i can use a class and a constructor, this code snippet is an small demo that demonstrate an example so using a class or a different function instead of memset will not help

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf I disagree with the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way for just the array

```
memset(a->arr,0,sizeof(a->arr))
```

Picked out the arr member just in case there are other structure members that do not need to be touched. Makes no difference in your example the following will do likewise

```
memset(a->arr,0,sizeof(A));
```

Answer (score 2):

> which one is more correct?

I'd argue neither. The easiest way would be to value initialize the allocated object:

```
A * a = new A();
```

Of course, this assumes that you actually have a good reason to `new` this object.

Comment: so for C which is better?

Comment: @rafiwiener Neither one is better, and neither one is worse. The compiler will most likely generate the exact same code for both variants.

Comment: @rafiwiener No clear "better", but I prefer the first one since the second one actually converts to the first one, and therefore would make the first one more "the better way"

Comment: @rafiwiener It is a matter of opinion. I would go for the second variant.

Comment: this is an argument during a code review with a co-worker, i  did the second way

Comment: @rafiwiener My way is better. I win :-)

Comment: Good luck using `new` in C :).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++ I would take advantage of C++11 features and use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    int arr[10]{};  // initializes array with all 0's
};

int main() {
    A * a = new A;
    for (auto e : a->arr) // ranged based for loop to show all of the 0's
        cout << e << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can see it running with this [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08bbcb67fa1abe45)

Answer (score 1):

While the *type* of each expression is different, the actual result, the pointer you pass to `memset`, will be equal in both cases.

Personally I would probably use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead of `memset` in a C++ program:

```
std::fill(std::begin(a->arr), std::end(a->arr), 0);
```

Also note that if you have more members in the structure, `sizeof(A)` will be different from `sizeof(a->arr)` (or `sizeof(A::arr)`).

Answer (score 1):

you can define a default construct function

```
struct A{
    int arr[10];
    A():arr(){}
};
```

Comment: There's really no need for that loop! Use value initialization: `A () : arr() {}`.

Comment: @ juanchopanza  i dont kown new features of c++11

Comment: It is an old C++03 feature